# Overlapping 2 Flash objects and controlling z-index

Tags: css, flash, overlap, z-index

I have two Flash objects on a webpage (call them A and B), and they overlap so one partially obscures the other. I don't seem to have any control over the z-index, to force B in front of A. Whatever I try, A always 'wins' and stays on the top!

I have read many people's posts about problem with getting HTML to show over the top of Flash...but nothing about when your two overlapping items are both Flash objects.

- I have tried various combinations of `wmode=opaque/transparent/window`
- I have tried CSS `position:absolute/relative` and `z-index:0/999`
- I have tried placing the HTML sections in a different order
- The problem is the same in IE and Firefox
- I do not want to use jQuery in this case

In my particular situation B must have `position:absolute` and `wmode=transparent`, and sit above A. A needs relative positioning and transparency is not required. **However, I have been testing without these restrictions**, and I still have no control over the overlap. Are some SWFs (ours are adverts sent by clients) created in such a way as to override any code control of z-index?

The reason for this arrangement is that A is a standard banner advert at the top of the page, and B is a 'page curl' effect where a corner peels down from the top right of the page.

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: IE6 and Firefox 2.0? Have you considered updating your browsers?

Comment: Not much point until 90% of my users have!  ;)

Comment: 90% of your users run IE6 or Firefox 2.0? Are you posting from three years ago or something?

Comment: Just remember that Flash is a seperate entity from the browser, and that it's way of doing things is probably not as expected. I would wonder why you need overlapping SWFs to begin with as well (lol!) and if you are working with old old browsers, maybe image adverts would be more reliable ;)

Comment: Reason for overlap now explained above. Reason for using old browsers is that users are like my dad - they don't know what an upgrade is, let alone how to do one. Far too many people out there still with old browsers using our websites! I would still like to know the answer to my question with regard to newer browsers, please.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to control the situation for one of my advert banners by getting rid of the `<object>` tag and just using `<embed>` on it's own. Then the  `wmode=opaque` trick worked in both IE and Firefox.

However, a different advert SWF did not respond to this change, and still shows above my page curl/corner peel.